# Sql Agent job that prompt for input?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-administration

I want to write a sql agent job which prompts for input while executing. Is it possible in sql server ? That input will be used as variable in the sql agent script.

Please help me out of this.

Thanks

Nitesh Kumar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is not possible in SQL server. If you want to give some manual input to the job, you can create a step in the job (first step) which reads the input from some file/database table etc. and then second step users first step's output as the input. 
You will have to create alternate ways to enter the manual input to the database table/file before the job starts executing.

One question though - Jobs are supposed to be run as per some schedule, doesn't your job follow some schedule?

Comment: no my job doesn`t follow any schedule . It is executed manually .

Answer (score 2):

Might be possible using xp_cmdshell to run a VB script or .bat file that prompts for input and writes the data back to the function.

Problem is that xp_cmdshell is usually turned off for security reasons because it allows someone within SQL to execute programs on the hosting server.

This example uses a powerscript to get some data, then it writes the data to a table, but it's all executed from xp_cmdshell

declare @CertFilePath varchar(500)
declare @SQL varchar(1000)
set @ScriptFilePath ='c:\myscripts\SomeScript.vbs'

CREATE TABLE #DataTable
(line varchar(255))

INSERT #DataTable
EXEC xp_cmdshell @SQL

select * from #DataTable

this code enables xp_CmdShell

EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE
GO
-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE
GO

this code disables xp_cmdshell

-- Sets xp_cmdshell enabled=false /reset back to disabled at the end of this
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE
GO
-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE
GO